# Indian H1B holder applying for travel insurance for Schengen visa

Tags: usa, schengen, indian-citizens, insurance

I am applying for a Schengen visa through Norway. I am an Indian citizen currently residing in the US as an H1B Holder.
My employer has provided my International proof of coverage, but it lacks emergency evacuation and repatriation. Therefore I am looking to buy travel insurance for myself.
It is mentioned [here](https://www.norway.no/en/usa/services-info/visitors-visa-res-permit/visitors-visa/#hand-in-doc) that the insurance should as a rule be purchased in your home country. If this is not possible it may be purchased in another country.

I would prefer to buy it in India, but the terms and conditions on the insurance websites seem to imply that the travel should be from India.

The US-based insurance policies are expensive, and not necessarily includes repatriation.

I am looking for the cheapest option here that should be enough to fulfill the visa requirement.

Comment: I won't give any advertisement for specific companies, but there are many European companies offering exactly what is needed for the Schengen visa, searching "Schengen travel insurance" on Google may help.

Comment: I guess my question is more around should I buy it in India(home country) or US(country of residence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess my question is more around should I buy it in India(home country) or US(country of residence)?

The **Visa Code** states that, by default, the insurance should be taken out in your country of residence.

Since you are applying as a US resident, you must have a policy that insures that any repatriation that can take place is to the United States.

> The US-based insurance policies are expensive, and not necessarily includes repatriation.

Such a policy would not be suitable, since it doesn't fulfill the conditions of Article 15(1) of the Visa Code.

Only where it is not possible to get such an US based insurance, can you seek one from another country.

In that case, assume the consulate will check to see that it includes a repatriation to the United States (your country of residence).

---

> **Visa Code**
> **Article 15 Travel medical insurance**
> 1. Applicants for a uniform visa for one or two entries **shall prove that they are in possession of adequate and valid travel medical insurance to cover any expenses which might arise in connection with repatriation for medical reasons**, urgent medical attention and/or emergency hospital treatment or death, during their stay(s) on the territory of the Member States.
> ...
> 4. Applicants shall, in principle, **take out insurance in their country of residence**. Where this is not possible, they shall seek to obtain insurance in any other country.